# Drawable not appearing on Button Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin.Forms - Android.
I'm using a Button Renderer on the Android platform to add an image onto an Android.Widget.Button. 
The Image file is stored in an Assets folder and not the usual Drawable folder.
I am setting the ImageSource of the button in XAML as normal and then in the renderer I am getting the image location and searching for it in the asset folder.
The drawable is created correctly and confirmed by checking the width and height which match, etc. but it is just not showing on the button itself.
The image file has build action of AndroidAsset but I've also tried AndroidResource and it still doesn't work.

```
FileImageSource fis = (FileImageSource)Element.ImageSource;
Stream stream = context.Assets.Open("images/" + fis.File);
Drawable d = Drawable.CreateFromStream(stream, null);
stream.Close();
Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, d, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ButtonView : Button {

    public new static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource), typeof(string), typeof(ButtonView), null);
        public new string ImageSource {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if(e.PropertyName == ButtonView.ImageSourceProperty.PropertyName) {
        SetImage();
    }
}

private void SetImage() {
    if (Element is ButtonView btn){
        Stream stream = context.Assets.Open("images/" + btn.ImageSource);
        Drawable d = Drawable.CreateFromStream(stream, null);
        stream.Close();
        Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, d, null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom renderer like following code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(CustomButton.Droid.CustomButton))]
namespace CustomButton.Droid
{
   public class CustomButton:ButtonRenderer
    {
        Context mcontext;
        public CustomButton(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            mcontext = context;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            AssetManager assets = mcontext.Assets;

            Stream input = assets.Open("main.png");

            var mydraw=Drawable.CreateFromStream(input, null);
            Control.Background = mydraw;
        }
    }
}
```

use it in xamarin forms.

```
   <StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button Text="Button"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

**Update**

If I used `Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, mydraw, null, null);` it could show the image above the text.

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            AssetManager assets = mcontext.Assets;

            Stream input = assets.Open("person.jpg");

            var mydraw = Drawable.CreateFromStream(input, null);
            Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, mydraw, null, null);
        }
```

Here is running screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Didn't want to set the background as image as I want to use the ripple background drawable for this. The image is an icon sitting on top of the ripple background.
I fixed it by replacing the default ImageSource property on my custom button view and this allowed me to use my code above.
I guess the issue is that XF tried to add the image but failed to find the file in the drawables folder and then wouldn't allow me to set the drawable after that point. So by replacing the ImageSource property XF didn't try to set the image initially and I was able to set it myself with no problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RussellCorbin I update my answer, I set `Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, mydraw, null, null); `  it could show the image above text. If the reply is helpful, please mark it  as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @RussellCorbin  Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: You basically just copied my code. The problem was when setting the image source in xaml. This would cause your code to not work.

Comment: I've already posted the answer. Used my original renderer code but I created a custom button view and replaced the ImageSource property with a string.